# Defining a closure in terms of another closure

Tags: closures, common-lisp

I have two closures that are complement of each other. I want to define one in terms of the other one. For example, lets say that we have the function `more-than` defined as follows

```
(defun more-than (v) #'(lambda (x) (> x v)))

CL-USER> (funcall (more-than 5) 7)
T
CL-USER> (funcall (more-than 5) 3)
NIL
```

and we want to define its complement, `less-than-or-equal` using the above closure. This seems to be not as easy as the above closure, as my attempts have not worked so far. Can somebody point out at a possible solution or tell me if this is common pattern at all (i.e., instead of defining the second closure independent of the first one).

Here are two of my tries that didn't work

```
;; compile time error
(defun less-than-or-equal (v)
  #'(lambda (x) #'(not (more-than v))))
;; returns nil for every comparison
(defun less-than-or-equal (v)
  #'(lambda (x) (not (more-than v))))
```

Comment: How did you try to implement it? The simple solution should work: `(defun less-than-or-equal (v) (complement (more-than v)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see that I missed on the `complement` and mistakenly tried to mimic the original closure definition! Nevertheless, I wonder if this can be achieved using `not`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use [`COMPLEMENT`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_comple.htm) to make the complement of a function:

```
(defun less-than-or-equal (v)
  (complement (more-than v)))
```

In your attempts you're using `NOT` to negate the function returned by `MORE-THAN`, rather than calling the function and negating the result. `X` is not used at all. To fix it, you would need to do

```
(defun less-than-or-equal (v)
  ;; The #' is not necessary here
  (lambda (x) (not (funcall (more-than v) x))))
```

But using `COMPLEMENT` is better.

Comment: `COMPLEMENT` essentially does what you've written explicitly in the second function.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, with the slight advantage of only calling `MORE-THAN` once rather than every time the resulting anonymous function is called. Of course you could bind that to a variable, but why bother when `COMPLEMENT` does it for you.

Comment: Oh, right. A better equivalence would be `(let ((mt (more-than v))) (lambda (x) (not (funcall mt) x))`